# IIS 8.5 serving dll for download instead of executing

Tags: iis, dll, cgi, iis-8.5, isapi

**The Problem:**

When I access a (32-bit) `DLL` via URL like ***http://localhost/somepath/some.dll?action*** IIS always thinks I want to download the file (with file size 0 byte) instead of executing the dll.

**What I tried so far:**

- added an entry for this specific DLL in ISAPI- and CGI-Restrictions
- enabled the "ISAPI-dll" Handler for *.dll with feature permissions read,script and execute.
- IIS User / AppPool Identity have full access rights to the physcal location of the dll
- App-Pool is running in classic mode and 32 bit applications are enabled
- I deleted the MIME-Type Entry for *.dll

Still any browser prompts a download window. I'm running out of ideas now. I'm currently using IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

The same application is running without troubles in IIS 5 on Windows 2000 SP4.

Any help or idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but what I discovered was that the web browser was actually caching the the file download.  I proved this by completely stopping IIS and accessing the URL and still it prompted me to download the file.  I then restarted IIS, confirmed the same issue existed still, tried from a new private window and the DLL ran instead of prompting me to download.

In short, try private mode or a different web browser after you've configured everything.

Comment: I can't believe I lost all my day for this stupid "hack". Thank you SO MUCH, Brian!

Comment: Saved me too, thx

Answer (score 1):

And as Windows 2000 was `32-bit` and Windows Server 2012 R2 is `64-bit` ( and as you said your DLL is `32-bit`) I expect that your issue is maybe possibly linked to [this issue.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/irfanahm/2008/12/15/how-to-use-a-32-bit-dll-in-asp-net-page-which-is-hosted-on-64-bit-iis/)

---

Does your DLL has been registered on server side by using command `regsvr32 <youdll>` (run that command from the windows directory) ?

- You may also try to set the MIME type Entry like this:

`Extension`   >   `Type`

`.dll`     >      `Assembly`  (Remove the stars and keep the dot on the extension)

- You may try to run the IIS host process in 32 bit mode
- You may try to create a wrapper of your dll's and host this wrapper dll's in COM+

Finally, according to [this similar issue](https://forums.iis.net/t/1166609.aspx?IIS%207%205%20DLL%20downloads%20instead%20of%20running%20What%20am%20I%20missing%20), you may refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/handlers/add) and double check that the Handler is properly setup.

Comment: In my case, I did all the necessary items, but I ended up having to remove the IIS feature, reinstall it, then apply the changes.  Not sure how IIS got corrupted.