# isapi dll force download

Tags: iis, dll, iis-7.5, isapi

I have a legacy ISAPI dll, that generally fulfills requests just fine, but occasionally I will get prompted to save the dll from my browser.  This is a known issue, with some good workarounds.  [IIS 8.5 serving dll for download instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281098/iis-8-5-serving-dll-for-download-instead-of-executing)  Hitting download will give you a zero byte file.

I am actually interested in doing the opposite of the workaround.  How can I force this (incorrect) behavior, ie, is it possible to trick the server to download the full ISAPI dll?  If so, what settings should I change.  I am running IIS 7.5.

[EDIT] For clarity, I am not trying to hack anything client side.  I doubt that's possible, but if it is I would really like to know.  I am trying to figure out if it is possible to get the server to give up the dll with just a plain old post/get request.  This is how I got it to give me the dll the first time, luckily it was zero bytes.

Thank you

Comment: This is not an appropriate question.  Why would you want to download the dll?  This would open a major security hole.

Comment: @Strom, I realize it is a security issue, and I am looking for the security hole so I can avoid it.  I am not asking how to hack the web site.  I am wondering how we might misconfigure our server, aside from the obvious directory browsing, that might lead our server to serve the dll (with all its bytes).  I was surprised when I saw the file being downloaded at all.  I wasn't trying to hack the server or break anything, I just made a request and the server gave me the dll, instead of processing the request.  Again, fortunately it was zero bytes.